# Missing recommended icon file in Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "AppName". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct
>   the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png
>   format for iOS versions >= 7.0.
>
> After you've corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards, The App Store team

Previously with Xcode 6 there was no warning or error but suddenly after update the Xcode 6 to Xcode 7 spontaneously I got this warning.

Comment: Goto Images.xcassets->AppIcon. Add all the missing images in correct resolutions.

Comment: @pkc456 There all the empty boxes are filled up with proper image size.

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 2 reasons for this issue

1. First one is, that you forget to set app icon in `Images.xcassets`.
2. Another one is, if you set the app icon, then check the size of app icon you set, it may not be of 120x120.

Comment: from beginning I used Images.xcassets and the most important thing that as I mention in my question that this issue occurred after updating the Xcode version.